# Maven is not found as a Right-Click option in EClipse

Tags: maven-plugin

I have installed and set the Maven plugin but when I right click on a project in project explorer I cannot find the Maven option so I cannot find Build dependencies either..any things that I should check maybe I have missed some settings?

Windows, Eclipse 3.6 JavaEE edition

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: yes, have tried that. maybe I am missing some setting and preferences somewhere... I dunno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had not installed th pluging correctly, removed and reinstalled it. working now.